# Web Api FromBody is null from web client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I would like to call Web Api method from C# client by my body variable in web api controller is null all the time.
How to set it correct ?
 client side:

```
IFileService imgService = new ImageServiceBll();
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(serverFile);
var dataImage = imgService.ImageToBase64(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://site.local/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // HTTP POST
    var data = new
    {
        imageData = dataImage,
        version = version
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/contenttool/SaveImage", data);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;
    }
}
```

Server Side:

```
public class ContentToolController : ApiController
{
    public IFileService FileService { get; set; }
    // POST api/contenttool
    public string SaveImage([FromBody]string data)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(data);
        JObject version = (JObject)jObject["version"];

        return "-OK-" + version;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think it has more to do with the fact that you technically aren't passing in a string.  You are passing in a JSON serialized string representation of an anonymous type, so the deserialization process in the Web Api is working against you.  By the time your request gets to the controller and that method, it isn't a string anymore.  Try changing your type on the SavImage method to be dynamic.  Like this:

```
public string SavImage([FromBody]dynamic data)
{
      JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(data);
      JObject version = (JObject)jObject["version"];

      return "-OK-" + version;
}
```

Unfortunately at that point you won't be able to use intellisense to get your properties out.  You will have to get the data out of the dynamic type via a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, object> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Convert.ToString(data));
```

Of course your other option would be to use an actual type that is shared between the client and the server.  That would make this a bit easier.

Comment: good point, but i found if send param like a string to PostAsJsonAsync it would work fine.

Comment: You are really working against the system.

Either send the data as a string and bind as a string,
OR send as JSON and bind to the same data object on the WebAPI side.

The second way is the right way to do it. Thus you avoid writing specific json manipulation code in your action method, the framework is there do it for you.

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer I agree for the most part with this, but if I want to serialize a list of objects, it would force me to create a new model simply to hold a list! This seems crazy doesnt it?

Comment: Where do you see that implied in my answer? You should be able to bind to a list in webapi without having to create a type containing a list

Answer (score 0):

The string value passed in the body probably needs to be prefixed with the `=` sign.

Comment: If you want to pass a string `Hello World` in the body, pass it as `=Hello World`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pass a JSON object into the method. A better way would be to have a strongly typed object as the parameter of the `SavImage` method without the `[FromBody]` attribute (which is really designed for passing simple values). Web API should take care of the serialization.