# Posted values to MVC6 controller are null

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am porting my web application from MVC5 to MVC6.  This function used to work fine in MVC5 but not in MVC6.

I am posting data, via AngularJS, to this WebAPI method but the search parameter is always null.  Ive tried decorating it with `[FromBody]` and `[FromHeader]` but neither seem to work.  The controller gets hit, the value is just null, what is wrong?

```
[HttpPost("AdvancedSearch")]
public List<MatchResult> AdvancedSearch(string searchParameter)
{
    var searchResults = service.GetResults(searchParameter);

    return searchResults;
}
```

My AngularJS call looks like this

```
myAPI.advancedSearch = function (searchParameter) {
    var url = '/api/advancedsearch/';

    // Request data
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: { searchParameter: searchParameter },
        url: url
    });
}
```

I verified that the data is sent, in Chrome webtools the "Request Payload" is correct

```
{searchParameter: "n1"}
```

Comment: Is the Content-type `application/json`?

Comment: Yes it is `application/json`, which is annoying as I wish it was that simple :)

Comment: Have you tried `[FromUri]string searchParameter`?

Comment: No, that doesnt seem to exist in MVC6 plus the payload isnt in the URI?

Comment: Why not `data:'searchParameter=n1'` as it is just a string?

Comment: @Chris pass stringified data like `JSON.stringify({ searchParameter: searchParameter })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this without using a model or querystring.  [This answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636606/94278) it but essentially you can use

```
[HttpPost]
public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
{
   //...
}
```

`value` will then contains all your post data.

**Edit**

For further reading please [see this post](https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/), including a table of all the binding situations and when it will and won't work!

Comment: But i guess using `dynamic` in your case is a overkill.

Comment: Its Less overkill than creating a model with only one or two properties.  Its a shame the ModelBinder doesnt just work like it used to.  I guess you'd have to play it on a case by case basis which is best to use in each scenario

Answer (score 1):

If you think an object is overkilling, you can always use querystrings. I know, looks "old", but it's still working I guess.

```
 myAPI.advancedSearch = function (searchParameter) {
    var url = '/api/advancedsearch?searchParameter=' + searchParameter ;

    // Request data
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: { },
        url: url
    });
 }

[HttpPost("AdvancedSearch")]
public List<MatchResult> AdvancedSearch([FromQuery]string searchParameter)
{
    var searchResults = service.GetResults(searchParameter);

    return searchResults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should boxing string into object in your action, because you sending object from AngularJS

```
public class SearchParamaterViewModel
{
    public string searchParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know this works, as I have used it elsewhere for logging in etc. But it seems massively overkill to have a model for every single interaction, especially when I am just doing a simple search?

Comment: @Chris it will depend on your needs I guess. If later you want your AdvancedSearch to contain 30 parameters querystring will no longer fit your needs, but once again it depends on what you plan for the future

Comment: @Chris I think you should boxing simply types every time.

Comment: I could understand if you had lots of POCOs being sent, but for example one of my signatures is a list of models... By this token Id have to create a new model that simply that holds a List! This is crazy no?