# Sending data to MVC Action via jQuery ajax, parameter is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I've gone through several questions here related to this, and so far none of them have fixed my particular issue. I'm sending data related to the selected rows in a DataGrid to an action on the server using ajax. The JavaScript code looks like this:

```
function addSelected() {
        var grid = $("#optionsGrid").dxDataGrid("instance");
        var gridData = grid.getSelectedRowsData();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/Options/AddRange",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ data: gridData })
        });
    }
```

And the action on the server (for now):

```
[HttpPost("api/[controller]/[action]")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> AddRange(string data)
{

    return Ok();
}
```

I've inspected it in a browser and the gridData value is definitely populated with the data I want before being sent to the server, and the action is hit, but the 'data' parameter is always null. I also tried putting the [FromBody] attribute on the parameter but it didn't change it. No matter what I name the data or whether or not I stringify it the parameter is null.

Changing the datatype to dynamic didn't help either, it was still null. The data needing to be sent is also included in the Request body upon inspection.

Comment: Have you checked that the data is sent in the request? In other words, does `gridData` have a value?

Comment: I would suggest you to use Fiddler or any similar tool and see in action exactly what is being sent to the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core MVC : How to get raw JSON bound to a string without a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type)

Comment: The data is encoded and included in the Request body when I inspected the request in the browser tools.

Comment: try adding an additional JSON.stringify to your gridData so you end up with JSON.stringify({ data: JSON.stringify(gridData) })

Comment: The additional JSON.stringify fixed it. If you change your comment to an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: that feels pretty hacky, check out the answers below before doing something like the double stringify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
function addSelected() {
    var grid = $("#optionsGrid").dxDataGrid("instance");
    var gridData = grid.getSelectedRowsData();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/Options/AddRange?data=" + JSON.stringify(gridData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked, had to drop the [FromBody] attribute from the parameter though.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name of `data` is in the stringify, you still need to specify that you are sending `data` as a parameter. Switch it like the below:

```
function addSelected() {
    var grid = $("#optionsGrid").dxDataGrid("instance");
    var gridData = grid.getSelectedRowsData();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/Options/AddRange",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(gridData) }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still null and I don't know why. It feel like this *should* be the correct way to do it.