# Why ajax send parameters to controller is null?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I sending a post request to controller by ajax:

This is my code in cshtml file:

```
<script>
    $("#btnSeachAjax").click(function () {
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();    
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Search")',
            data: { id: "1",title:"ba"},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": token
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#data").html(data);
            }
            ,
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

This is my code in controller:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Search")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromBody] string id,string title)
        {
            var movie = await _context.Movies.FindAsync(id);
            return View(movie);
        }
```

Value of `id` , `title` in controller = `null`.

Why ajax send parameters to controller is null?

I using Asp.net mvc net core 3.1.

Comment: Please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930231/sending-data-to-mvc-action-via-jquery-ajax-parameter-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromBody] string id,string title)`

> Value of id , title in controller = null.

Based on your action method and accepted parameters, you can try to modify the Ajax code as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Search")'+'?title=ba',
    data: JSON.stringify("1"),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    //...
```

Besides, you can create a viewmodel and modify your action accept a complex type parameter, like below.

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

*Action method*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromBody] MyData myData)
{
    //...
```

*On JS client side*

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Search")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: "1", title: "ba" }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    //...
```

Comment: And you can know more information about "Model Binding in ASP.NET Core" from this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: the solution 1, only send title,  i had send ok by MyData class.

Comment: Case only send 1 parameter, i have to send by URL?

Comment: `the solution 1, only send title` It works for me, please check the actual request and posted data in browser f12 developer tools Network tab.

Comment: `Case only send 1 parameter, i have to send by URL?` Passing these two parameters trough querystring is ok, but you need to remove `[FromBody]` attribute from id parameter.