# What's causing the parameter to be null?

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Asp.Net Core 2.0 and web api to build a rest service.  All works fine except for HTTPPost.

```
[HttpPost("LoginUser")]
public IActionResult LoginUser(LoginUser loginUser)
{
   return Ok(loginUser);
}
```

loginUser is always null. I am testing with fiddler and my route is http://localhost:53250/api/User/LoginUser

and the body is

```
{"EmailAddress":"xx@xx.com","Password":"123456789"}
```

Fiddler hits the link just fine, but payload is always null.

I have also tried

```
[HttpPost("LoginUser")]
public IActionResult LoginUser([FromBody] LoginUser loginUser)
{
    return Ok(loginUser);
}
```

In this case, it doesn't hit the function.

This is the LoginUser definition:

```
public class LoginUser
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Tested locally and it works. Test it with Postman, choose Post, Body->Raw and type JSON, it worked for me

Comment: also note that you action should not be `void`. return `IActionResult`

Comment: Same result with Postman.  Are you using core 2.0?

Comment: Nkosi, It makes no difference, payload is still null.  I'm just testing the communication to see if it hits, not worried about returning a specific value yet...

Comment: Yes. Core 2.0, Have you added a breakpoint in the post?

Comment: yes, it stops, but the payload is null.  Nothing is being passed to the function parameters.  I just tried a simple text string and it arrived to the Post null...

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you share how you're testing the API

Comment: I'm testing as you suggested using postman.  The function is being hit, but the payload is null always...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved. When I added my UserController, I did so as a class and derived from controller. I deleted it and added it as a new item and picked web api core controller. Now all is working just fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your action should be:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("LoginUser")]
    public IActionResult LoginUser([FromBody] LoginUser loginUser)
    {
        return Ok(loginUser);
    }
}
```

See, `[HttpPost("LoginUser")]` affects only route and doesn't relate to `LoginUser` object type.

Update: you need `[FromBody]` as ASP.NET Core [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) by default looks into `[FromForm]` binding source. And `[FromBody]` attribute indicates that you want to bind a parameter to data in the request body.

Update 2: you also should add  `Content-Type: application/json` header to request. ASP.NET Core selects input formatters based on the this header.

Update 3: if you really need to get body data as raw string, look into [ASP.NET Core MVC : How to get raw JSON bound to a string without a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type). It suggests using `[FromBody] dynamic data`

Comment: I know that.  But I am passing the body object with a valid LoginUser to the http call.  It's still null...

Comment: @JohnBaird Have you actually tried this solution?  Looks correct to me.

Comment: @JohnBaird have you added `Content-Type: application/json` header? You pass json data in body and you have corresponding model `LoginUser` => it's no sense to expect body as a `string` (like you have in second example: [FromBody] string loginUser).

Comment: Sorry, but I updated my post after numerous tries with LoginUser object.  I tried to pass a simple string which is constantly null also.  I am back to using LoginUser..  I have Content-type set in the headers as you specify. The payload is still null.

Comment: @JohnBaird do you use `services.AddMvcCore()` or `services.AddMvc()`? If `AddMvcCore` then you also need to have `AddJsonFormatters()`: `services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();`

Comment: Issue has been solved.  When I added my UserController, I did so as a class and derived from controller.  I deleted it and added it as a new item and picked web api core controller.  No all is working just fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsing is case sensitive. Your JSON is in the wrong case.
Should be: {"EmailAddress":"xx@xx.com","Password":"123456789"}.

Comment: Sorry I copied the conversion from visual studio. Here' what I 'm sending from fiddler: {"EmailAddress":"xx@xx.com","Password":"123456789"}.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have properties in your request model that are set to `{get;
  private set;}`, the values will not get populated. Make them public by removing `private`. Also constructors
  aren't utilized.
- If you're reading plain text from the body, see if `[FromForm]`
  works.