# For the XMLHttpRequest in WebApi, use the blob data type to initiate a request to the server. How does C# .net core receive and parse it?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blob

The web front end uses the Blob data type request as follows:

```
var $jsonTotal = ___config___["data_json"];
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{1}" , ___playerID___);
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{2}" , ___platfrom___);
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{3}" , ___serverID___);
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{4}" , $total);
var $blob = new Blob([$jsonTotal], { type: "application/json" });//text/plain;charset=utf-8
var $oXHR  = new XMLHttpRequest();
$oXHR.responseType = "blob";
$oXHR.open(___config___["upload_method"], ___servicePath___);
$oXHR.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    console.log("upload--ok--");
}, true);
$oXHR.send( $blob );
```

It can be seen that the Blob is actually a layer on the Json data package. The question now is: How to get blob data and parse this data in C# .net core environment?

On the server side, I have tried it in the following way, and all ended in failure (no data was obtained):

[HttpPost]
public void Log( Blob blob)

[HttpPost]
public void Log( byte[] bytes)

Front end code：

```
var $jsonTotal = ___config___["data_json"];
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{1}" , ___playerID___);
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{2}" , ___platfrom___);
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{3}" , ___serverID___);
$jsonTotal = $jsonTotal.replace("{4}" , $total);
var $blob = new Blob([$jsonTotal], { type: "application/json" });//text/plain;charset=utf-8
var $oXHR  = new XMLHttpRequest();
$oXHR.responseType = "blob";
$oXHR.open(___config___["upload_method"], ___servicePath___);
$oXHR.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    console.log("upload--ok--");
}, true);
$oXHR.send( $blob );
```

Server-side code：

[HttpPost]
public void Log( byte[] bytes)

I hope that the C# server can get the Blob type data from the web front end and get the Json data from the Blob data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FromBody` attribute and accept `JObject` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type)