# can I take any object in webapi? (.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("[action]")]
public ActionResult Get([FromQuery] object RequestModel)
{
    try
    {
        IResult runResult = new Result();
        ICommand api = Factory.APIName((Enums.APIName)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Enums.APIName), 9901));
        var responseModel = api.HandleCommand<object, object>(RequestModel, out runResult);
        api.Dispose();

        if (runResult.Success)
            return StatusCode(200, responseModel);
        else
            return StatusCode(200, new ERC_Models.BaseResponse() { StateCode = 999 });
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

how can do it?
maybe use with Generic? but I tried, it response 404

the reason is I wish all entrance can through one webapi, and go factory layer
so I need can take any parameters webapi action...

thanks!

Comment: Hi, @XianYe Lee, you could try custom `Middleware` to handle all request in one entrance. And go factory layer with `HttpContext.Request.QueryString` which contains all parameters.

Comment: Hi,@MichaelWang, I'll try your suggestion,Thanks!

Comment: may this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type