# Unit test custom InputFormatter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, inputformatter

I have added a custom InputFormatter from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47807117/1093406 but want to add unit testing for the class.

Is there an easy way to do this?
I'm looking at the `InputFormatterContext` parameter to `ReadRequestBodyAsync` and it seems to be complex with lots of other objects required to construct it and it looks difficult to mock.
Has anyone been able to do this?

I'm using xUnit and Moq on .Net5

Code

```
public class RawJsonBodyInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public RawJsonBodyInputFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/json");
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
        }
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the aspnetcore tests for `InputFormatter` and got this code from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/test/Formatters/TextInputFormatterTest.cs):

```
context = new InputFormatterContext(
                new DefaultHttpContext(),
                "something",
                new ModelStateDictionary(),
                new EmptyModelMetadataProvider().GetMetadataForType(typeof(object)),
                (stream, encoding) => new StreamReader(stream, encoding));
```

I also got some other useful hints from [JsonInputFormatterTestBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/test/Formatters/JsonInputFormatterTestBase.cs)

Answer (score 1):

I only created a `ControllerContext` for mocking and it also has to instantiate a `HttpContext`:

```
controllerBase.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
{
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        RequestServices = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddOptions()
            .AddAuthenticationCore(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = MyAuthHandler.SchemeName;
                options.AddScheme(MyAuthHandler.SchemeName, s => s.HandlerType = typeof(MyAuthHandler));
            }).BuildServiceProvider()
    }
};
```

For mocking the other properties in your case, you could take a look at [BodyModelBinderTests.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/test/ModelBinding/Binders/BodyModelBinderTests.cs), if there is something you can use.

Comment: While this answer didn't directly solve my problem, your link to the aspnetcore tests did point me to more information that allowed me to solve it.

Comment: Then mark your own answer as accepted one. 

Comment: StackOverflow won't let you mark your own answer as accepted for an hour after posting - I have no idea why 