# Model to JsonElement

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, jsonelement

What is the best/quickest way to convert a Model to JsonElement?

**Background:**
I have existing code for a Controller that passes JsonElement from the request body to a repository.  Now I have another Controller that first needs to do some logic on the Model, then I want to pass this to the same repository as the first controller.  The problem is I cannot seem to figure a way of converting the Model to JsonElement other than this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody] MyModel model)
{
    //Amazing logic done to model remove as it is not needed
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
    using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    var results = _repository.Insert(doc.RootElement);
    //Amazing logic parsing the results
}
```

This does work, just seems like way too many steps.  If there is no other way then so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the controller you can use [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0) which has [`SerializeToElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetoelement?view=net-6.0) and [`SerializeToDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetodocument?view=net-6.0) methods:

```cs
var element = JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(model);
var results = _repository.Insert(element);
```

For controller action you can just accept `JsonElement`/`JsonDocument` as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody] JsoneElement model)
{
    var results = _repository.Insert(model);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my solution is better than yours, but I think it is worth a try.

You can get a raw json from a body  (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type)). Then, you can create a JsonElement from it without a need to serialize the model to json. You will need to deserialize the `MyModel` explicitly in your code, but it should be done anyway (and will be done either by you or by the model binding mechanism)